# Why does discord not update through the package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have been successfully updating discord by using the `.deb` it asks me to download as an 'update' every so often, but this is really weird to me. Shouldn't the `.deb` allow my package manager to track their repository, and therefore not need to download a new one at each update? Is there some setting that I don't have set that causes this to happen, or is this something on discord's end? This is one of the only packages that behaves this way for me.

EDIT: I was asked what the apt-cache policy returned for discord, so I ran that from a terminal and here are the results:

```
discord:
  Installed: 0.0.14
  Candidate: 0.0.14
  Version table:
 *** 0.0.14 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I don't really know how to read this, but I note that there's no repository recorded here, where there ought to be if there was one, so I guess discord is sending individual programs out via its `.deb`s rather than creating a repository for them to pull updates in from.

Comment: Did you add a ppa for discord to your system sources list?

Comment: +1 to @David. @LGS, please show the output of `apt-cache policy discord`. If it contains only `100 /var/lib/dpkg/status` then you do not have software source for Discord.

Comment: I just edited to add the return of that command. I'm guessing that I'll need a third-party ppa to keep discord up to date, as @David suggested. I'm going to self-answer so that this isn't an open question anymore unless one of you would like to do that.

Comment: @N0rbert I did put an answer but was told it was no good so removed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your output of `apt-cache policy discord` indicates that you have installed Discord using local deb-file. The system is not configured to have special `sources.list` for Discord, moreover Discord does not provide it.

So if you want automatic updates of Discord you have two options:

- install Discord from [FlatPak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.discordapp.Discord) with

  ```
  sudo apt install flatpak
  flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
  flatpak install flathub com.discordapp.Discord
  ```
- install Discord from [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/discord) with

  ```
  snap install discord
  ```

But from my personal experience I can say that Discord releases its updates not too frequent, so it is acceptable to install it from downloaded deb-file. I'm doing so and happy with this. So you can leave things as they now is.

Comment: I installed via snap and it still launched with the "Download" deb file option.  They seem to be doing a lot more frequent releases these days.

Comment: I'm surprised that there's not an add-on to allow simple links/URL to be added to apt's sources.list, apt update would then check the file headers and install if there was some difference? Surely that has been done?

Comment: Not too often is old news! Lately, it's been asking me to download a new .deb file almost every week, super freaking annoying, and won't let you keep using the current/old version that it installed. Grrrr to discord lol

Answer (score 2):

As personally I don't trust snaps, I have created an Ansible script to configure Discord to not complain about updates and update it automatically weekly, using a systemd timer.

https://gitlab.com/dustwolf/discord-update

The readme contains installation instructions, etc.

The solution is comparable to using a snap, but is not reliant on the centralised snap provider and does not create the overhead of snaps.